# Non-continuous linear functional

Tags: functional-analysis

"There exists a normed space with a discontinuous linear functional".  Consider the space $c_{00}$ of all sequences of real numbers with only finitely many nonzero terms, with the supremum norm.  The functional $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n x(n)$ is discontinuous.

[Does existence of a non-continuous linear functional depend on Axiom of Choice?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/775032/does-existence-of-a-non-continuous-linear-functional-depend-on-axiom-of-choice)

I quoted from this link. How to show this is discontinuos?

Sınce every $x\in c_{00}$ has finite nonzero term $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n x(n)$ is bounded but why writer said this functional is discontinuous?

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ where continuous then for every sequence $(x_n)$ in $c_{00}$ converging to $x$ we would have $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(x_n)=f(\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n)=f(x)$.

Let $e_i$ be the element of $c_{00}$ such that $e_i(j)=1$ if $i=j$ and $e_i(j)=0$ otherwise. Consider $x_n=(1/n)e_n$, then $\|x_n\|=1/n$, so $x_n\to 0$, but $f(x_n)=1$ for every $n$, so $\lim f(x_n)=1\neq f(\lim x_n)=f(0)=0$ and $f$ is discontinuous.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, a more easily understandable, and very natural, as opposed to artificial, example is in terms of $L^2$ Sobolev spaces on the circle. For $s\in\mathbb R$, the $s^{th}$ Sobolev space consists of Fourier series $\sum_n c_n e^{2\pi inx}$ with $\sum_n (1+n^2)^s\cdot |c_n|^2<\infty$. This can be defined either as the completion of the space of smooth function on the circle with respect to the obvious norm (square root of that expression), or as the collection of distributions $u$ so that $c_n=u(e^{2\pi ix})$ satisfies that inequality.

Sobolev imbedding includes the assertion that $H^{1/2+\epsilon}$ consists of continuous functions.

It is easy to write functionals, in terms of those Fourier coefficients (which are abstractly just in some weighted $L^2$ spaces) which are continuous on $H^1$ but not on $H^0=L^2$. E.g., "evaluation-at-a-point".