# Difference between $X^*$ and $X'$

Tags: functional-analysis, notation

I have  some confusion in notations

i have  seen this notation $X^*$  and $X'$ in many books generally in hahn -banach theorem

In some book it is  written as $X'$ and while in other book  its written as  $X^*$

My question is that

Are  both $X^*$  and $X'$ have same meaning or different meaning ?

Comment: It depend on the context. In context of functional analysis yes, but sometime $X'$ may be seen as the algebraic dual and $X^*$ as the topological dual.

Comment: @joshua The other way around (i.e. $X'$ is the continuous dual, $X^*$ is the algebraic dual) is also used. Arguably moreso? Not sure on that though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In functional analysis usually $X^*$ denotes the space of all continuous linear functionals, while algebraic dual $X'$ or ''$X$ with hash'' is space of all linear functional, not nessesary continuous, notice that in finite dimenshion case this spaces are equial.
Also, here is a usefull example of non-continuous linear functional [Non-continuous linear functional](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3565912/non-continuous-linear-functional)